# Can we change iPhone app binary after it has been approved and ready for sales

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've recently submitted an iPhone app to the app store and my app got approved from apple team, now my client wants few minor changes(which doesn't deserve a new version).

I can change the app but I couldn't find how to replace the binary for the latest version of my app.

Is it possible to upload or update existing application without adding a new version?

Comment: What do you think the point of approval would be if developers could arbitrarily change their binaries afterwards?

Comment: LOL.... do you think apple's developers are dumb...

Comment: I didn't said that I want to change the binary without approval.
I just asked is it possible to update or not?

:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. There is no way to alter the binary you submitted earlier, without going through the approval process once again. You should resubmit your application in Apple Connect and set a higher version number.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!!
:)

Although I was almost sure yet wanted to confirm from community.
Many thanks!

Comment: whats the procedure to submit it again, I am going to Product > Archive > Submit, when I give itunesconnect credentials the message is shown "No suitable application records were found, Please make sure that you have setup a record for this application on iTunes Connect"..

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to push updated binary code to the live app on the store. You can do it by only the way is to update your Application with new version.

Hope it will guide you.